# Insert with HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to insert a new record to MySQL.
database: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RZAS.png)
Entity class:`package entites;
// Generated Aug 11, 2017 1:32:55 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * UserMonhoc generated by hbm2java
 */
public class UserMonhoc  implements java.io.Serializable {

```
 private UserMonhocId id;
 private Monhoc monhoc;
 private User user;
 private Date thoigianDk;

public UserMonhoc() {
}

public UserMonhoc(UserMonhocId id, Monhoc monhoc, User user, Date thoigianDk) {
   this.id = id;
   this.monhoc = monhoc;
   this.user = user;
   this.thoigianDk = thoigianDk;
}

public UserMonhocId getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(UserMonhocId id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Monhoc getMonhoc() {
    return this.monhoc;
}

public void setMonhoc(Monhoc monhoc) {
    this.monhoc = monhoc;
}
public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
public Date getThoigianDk() {
    return this.thoigianDk;
}

public void setThoigianDk(Date thoigianDk) {
    this.thoigianDk = thoigianDk;
}
```

}

`

Code:

```
public boolean InsertStudent(String idUS, String idMH) {

    try {
        sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        UserMonhoc umh = new UserMonhoc();
        String hql2 = "INSERT INTO User_Monhoc(user_id,mh_id) VALUES('" + idUS + "','" + idMH + "')";
        System.out.println(hql2);
        Query query = sf.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql2);
        query.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

it don't work. 
Thank you.

Comment: You should show the entity class and give the exact error message.

Comment: Ok. it was updated!

Comment: Why oh why? Just use `session.persist(umh)`. If you want to use SQL queries to insert data in your database, you shouldn't be using Hibernate, but JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

> Insert with HQL query

You don't use a HQL query.

This invocation :

```
Session.createSQLQuery(...)
```

creates a native SQL Query.

Anyway, you could not use INSERT in this way in HQL.

According to [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html#d0e2116) :

> Only the INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... form is supported. You cannot
>   specify explicit values to insert.

But using a HQL query will not solve your problem as you want to specify values to insert.

To persist an entity, the most natural way of doing in Hibernate is invoking the`Session.persist()` method :

```
UserMonhoc umh = new UserMonhoc();
... // set fields of the object
sf.getCurrentSession().persist(umh);
```

But to do it, `UserMonhoc` of course has to be declared as an entity.
I specify it as I don't see any Hibernate annotation in your actual entity. These are maybe declared in the xml configuration...